# "Normalizing" a CSV file

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv

I have a CSV file for help desk calls.  The same ticket might have 1,2, or even 5 records based on the number of updates it has.  (One field is different, all other fields are identical).

I want to take the mostly-duplicate records and create one record with the differences concatenated into it.  Having programmed in the past, but being a newbie to PowerShell, I could use some help.

So, based on a previous question I asked, here's what I have so far.  Assuming data like this:

```
ID, Date, Comment
345, 1/1/16, Moss has reported a fire in the I/T Room
345, 1/1/16, Never mind, he has sent an e-mail about it.
346, 1/2/16, Someone on the 5th floor is complaining about a man under her desk.
347, 2/1/16, Jen says she has broken the Internet.
347, 2/1/16, Douglas is very angry, we need a fix ASAP!
347, 2/1/16, Roy was playing a joke on her.  Closing ticket.
```

I have the following code:

```
$FileList  = Import-Csv "Call List.csv"
$incidents = $FileList | Group ID
foreach($group in $incidents)
{
    # What goes here?
}
```

How do I take the comments from the 2nd, 3rd, etc. line in the group, concatenate it to the comment in the first, and write the file out?

Comment: Did you mean that one field is the same (ID) and the others (Date, Comment) are variable? That is, you want to deduplicate on the ID and concatenate the (Date+Comment)s into one report?

Comment: I'm not interested in changes in any other field than comment.  All other field SHOULD be duplicated for the same ID, and if not, I really don't care.  I'll just use the information in the first record.   It's only the comments I care about preserving in duplicate ID records.

Comment: This whole plan sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: I'd be more worried about the fire in the IT Room, whether or not anyone has sent an email about it.

Comment: Forget the fire - someone has broken the internet. Far more serious!.

Comment: "The whole plan sounds like a bad idea".  I'm not really sure what you mean by that.  We need to review help desk calls, and the help desk system we have is (unfortunately) what we have.  It dumps out a log in CSV format, and that's what we have to deal with, multiple lines for the same ticket.  I could just dump the extra lines, but I'd lose the information about how the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 4):

The Group-Object produces an object with Name and Group, Group containing all the items in that group. You can extract them and create a new object using something like this:

```
$incidents = $FileList | Group-Object ID | % {
    New-Object psobject -property @{
        ID = $_.Name
        Date = $_.Group[0].Date
        Comment = ($_.Group | Select -Expandproperty Comment) -Join "`n"
    }
}
```

(not tested as I am currently on a Mac)

Comment: [How to install PowerShell on Mac OS X](http://www.howtogeek.com/267858/how-to-install-microsoft-powershell-on-linux-or-os-x/) ;-)

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler - yes I know, but but haven't got around to installing because I am too busy playing with bash on Windows 10 Anniversary. What a crazy world!.

Comment: Man, between these two comments here and the sample data from OP this question is priceless xD.

Comment: To be fair, I did steal the idea of the sample data from another poster on this forum.

Answer (score 1):

I'd first get a list of the unique IDs, for example:

```
$Ids = $FileList | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Id -Unique
```

Then I'd look through the list of tickets and build up a "report" for each ID:

```
foreach($Id in $Ids){
  # Get all incident logs for this Id:
  $logs = $FileList | ?{$_.Id -eq $Id}

  $report = ""

  foreach($log in $logs){
    $report += $log.Date + ": " + $log.Comment + "; "
  }

  # Now you can write the text out
  $report | Out-File $Outfile -Append
}
```

Hope that gives you an idea.